# ora-01722 Invalid number liquibase changeSet (in Toad script works)

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I'm trying to execute an update to database using liquibase. The problem is that I have some scripts that creates materialized views and I get the error:

> liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for
>   change set
>   changelog/20160323192000_mviews.xml::20160323192000#1::marius: Reason:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number

When I execute them in Toad for Oracle 11, the mviews are created without problems.

```
<changeSet id="20160323192000#1" author="marius">
    <sql splitStatements="false"><![CDATA[
        CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Activities_Others_M AS SELECT * FROM Activities;
     ]]></sql>
</changeSet>
```

I also tried to create table in liquibase changeSet and also is not working. Only a normal view is working.

Comment: same database?  it looks like a data problem

Comment: It's same database. I checked that

Comment: Maybe Liquibase is doing something odd under the hood; not sure how that can fail with that error, at least with a DDL trigger, which would affect Toad too. [According to this](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Oracle+Extensions) there is a specific extension to create an MV - maybe you need to use that? (I assume it doesn't mind the semicolon; don't see how that could lead to that error anyway!)

Comment: I added liquibase oracle extension to pom and I modified changeSet to: `<changeSet id="20160323192000#1" author="marius">
    <ora:createMaterializedView subquery="SELECT * FROM Activities" viewName="Activities_Others_M"/>
</changeSet>`. It saved changeSet in DatabaseChangeLog, but mview was not created.

Comment: I suspect you have some implicit data type conversion going on in your select statement. And the NLS settings from within Toad are different than those when running through JDBC. Is `activities` a view or a real table?

Comment: It is a complicated view actually. It has 800 rows... My doubt is: if it is a datatype conversion problem in the view, why is working when I create a view instead mview?

Comment: Because `create view` doesn't actually read the data, but when you create the mview it has to. You should fix your underlying view to avoid the evil implicit data type conversion

Comment: Is dificult to modify the view because Toad is not giving me an error, and I don't know from where to start.

Comment: @marius9228 Here are a few things to look for in the view: any columns where dates are stored as strings, any instances of `TO_DATE` or `TO_CHAR`.  It's usually best to use date-only functions and avoid ever converting between dates and strings.

Comment: I made a small application with ojdbc6 (11g) to run my big select. It runs fine without problem like Toad. To me it seems like a liquibase problem...